# How to vary multiple parameters with lapply in R

Tags: r, function, nested, lapply

In an attempt to avoid nesting for loops 6-7 times, I am trying to use lapply to find the proportion of randomly drawn values (that are combined in a certain way) that exceed some arbitrary thresholds values. The problem is that I have several parameters that each vary a certain number of ways, and these, in turn, will affect how the values are combined. The goal is to use the results in an ANOVA to see how varying these parameters contributes to reaching those thresholds. However, I don't understand how to do this. I have a feeling that anonymous functions could be useful, but I don't understand how they work with more than 1 parameter.

I tried to simplify the code as much as possible. But again, there are just so many parameters that must be included.

```
trials = 10
data_means = c(0,1,2,3)
prior_samples = c(2, 8, 32)
data_SD = c(0.5, 1, 2)
thresholds = c(10, 30, 80)
```

The idea is that there are two distributions, [data and prior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGJ5j.jpg), which I draw values from. I always draw one from data, but I draw a sample (see `prior_samples`) of values from the prior distribution. There are four different values that determine the mean of the data distribution (see `data_means`), but the values are drawn the same number of times (determined by `trials`) from each of these four "versions" of the data distribution. These are then put into nested lists:

```
set.seed(123)

data_list = list()
for (nMean in data_means){  #the data values
  for (nTrial in 1:trials){
    data_list[[paste(nMean, sep="_")]][[paste(nTrial, sep="_")]] = rnorm(1, nMean, 1)
  }
}

prior_list = list()
for (nSamples in prior_samples){  #the prior values
  for (nTrial in 1:trials){
    prior_list[[paste(nSamples, sep="_")]][[paste(nTrial, sep="_")]] = rnorm(nSamples, 0, 1)
  }
}
```

Then I create another list for the prior values, because I want to calculate the means and standard deviations (SD) of the samples of prior values. I include normal SD, as well as SD/2 and SD*2:

```
prior_SD = list("mean"=0, "standard_devations"=list("SD/2"=0, "SD"=0, "SD*2"=0))
prior_mean_SD = rep(list(prior_SD), trials)
prior_nested_list = list("2"=prior_mean_SD, "8"=prior_mean_SD, "32"=prior_mean_SD)
for (nSamples in 1:length(prior_samples)){
  for (nTrial in 1:trials){
    prior_nested_list[[nSamples]][[nTrial]][["mean"]]=mean(prior_list[[nSamples]][[nTrial]]) 
    prior_nested_list[[nSamples]][[nTrial]][["standard_devations"]][["SD/2"]]=sum(sd(prior_list[[nSamples]][[nTrial]])/2)
    prior_nested_list[[nSamples]][[nTrial]][["standard_devations"]][["SD"]]=sd(prior_list[[nSamples]][[nTrial]])
    prior_nested_list[[nSamples]][[nTrial]][["standard_devations"]][["SD*2"]]=sum(sd(prior_list[[nSamples]][[nTrial]])*2)
  } 
}
```

Then I combinde the values from the data list and the last list, using `list.zip` from `rlist`:

```
library(rlist)
dataMean0 = list.zip(dMean0=data_list[["0"]], pSample2=prior_nested_list[["2"]], 
                        pSample8=prior_nested_list[["8"]], pSample32=prior_nested_list[["32"]])
dataMean1 = list.zip(dMean1=data_list[["1"]], pSample2=prior_nested_list[["2"]], 
                        pSample8=prior_nested_list[["8"]], pSample32=prior_nested_list[["32"]])
dataMean2 = list.zip(dMean2=data_list[["2"]], pSample2=prior_nested_list[["2"]], 
                        pSample8=prior_nested_list[["8"]], pSample32=prior_nested_list[["32"]])
dataMean3 = list.zip(dMean3=data_list[["3"]], pSample2=prior_nested_list[["2"]], 
                        pSample8=prior_nested_list[["8"]], pSample32=prior_nested_list[["32"]])
all_values = list(mean_difference0=dataMean0, mean_difference1=dataMean1, 
             mean_difference2=dataMean2, mean_difference3=dataMean3)
```

Now comes the tricky part. I combine the data values and the prior values in `all_values` by using this custom function for the Kullback-Leibler divergence. As you can see, there are 6 parameters that varies:

- `mean_diff` refers to the means of the data distribution (`data_means`). It is named `mean_diff` beacsue it refers to the difference in mean between the prior distribution (which is always 0), and the data distribution (which can be 0, 1, 2 or 3).
- `trial` refers to `trials`,
- `pSample` refers to the numbers of samples drawn from the prior distribution (`prior_samples`)
- `p_SD` refers to the calculations of the SD based on the prior samples (normal SD, SD/2, SD*2)
- `data_SD` refers to the SD of the data distribution, determined by `data_SD`
- `threshold` refers to `thresholds`

The Kullback-Leibler divergence function:

```
kld = function(mean_diff, trial, pSample, p_SD, data_SD, threshold){
  prior_mean = all_values[[mean_diff]][[trial]][[pSample]][["mean"]]
  data_mean = all_values[[mean_diff]][[trial]][["mean"]]
  prior_SD = all_values[[mean_diff]][[trial]][[pSample]][["standard_devations"]][[p_SD]]
  posterior_SD = sqrt(1/(1/
                           ((all_values[[mean_diff]][[trial]][[pSample]][["standard_devations"]][[p_SD]]
                             *all_values[[mean_diff]][[trial]][[pSample]][["standard_devations"]][[p_SD]]))
                         +1/(data_SD*data_SD)))

  length(
    which(
      (log(prior_SD/posterior_SD) +
         (((posterior_SD*posterior_SD) +
             (prior_mean -
                (((data_SD*data_SD))/
                   ((data_SD*data_SD)+(prior_SD*prior_SD))*prior_mean + 
                   ((prior_SD*prior_SD))/
                   ((data_SD*data_SD)+(prior_SD*prior_SD))*data_mean))^2)
          /(2*(prior_SD*prior_SD)))-0.5 
       +  
         log(posterior_SD/prior_SD) + 
         ((((prior_SD*prior_SD)) + 
             (prior_mean -
                (((data_SD*data_SD))/
                   ((data_SD*data_SD)+(prior_SD*prior_SD))*prior_mean + 
                   ((prior_SD*prior_SD))/
                   ((data_SD*data_SD)+(prior_SD*prior_SD))*data_mean))^2)
          /(2*(posterior_SD*posterior_SD)))-0.5
      )>=threshold))/trials
}
```

So the question is how can one use lapply on the list with all the values (`all_values`) while using all the different combinations of the six parameters that are included? The data I want to end up with is the proportions of values (percentage of `trials`) that exceed the `thresholds` in all the parameter combinations.

I can't find the info I need, so any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered purrr::pmap to iterate over multiple arguments?

Comment: The short answer is that you cannot pass more than one parameter with 1 lapply,  So ito use lapply you will have to build a vector of all your combinations say `V <- cbind(mean_diff, trial)` and `lapply(1:nrow(v), function(i) {... V[i,1]... V[i,2]) ...})`. You can also use `mapply` or `Map` which will enable you to pass more than 1 parameter directly. `Map(function(x,y) {...x ..y}, x=mean_diff, y=trial)`

Comment: Try the foreach package this package lets you pass multiple variables. You can combine that with iterator functions that will help make this super easy. Here is a link to the docs: 
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/foreach/foreach.pdf

Comment: Check this out https://adv-r.hadley.nz/functionals.html